# How do you count cells in rows containing a certain partial string?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, countif

I have cells being imported containing words.

| Name | Location | Address | Access A | Access B | Access C... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | Location1 | Address1 | access RC | access SC | Access SC |
| Name2 | Location2 | Address2 | access SC | access SC | Access RC |
| Name3 | Location3 | Address3 | access blue SC | access RC | access red RC |

What I am trying to get is add an extra column on the right where it counts for every line the amount of times where the cell contains for ex RC and SC

Example of what i am looking for

| Name | Location | Address | Access A | Access B | Access C... | Total RC | Total SC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | Location1 | Address1 | access RC | access SC | Access SC | 1 | 2 |
| Name2 | Location2 | Address2 | access SC | access SC | Access RC | 1 | 2 |
| Name3 | Location3 | Address3 | access blue SC | access RC | access red RC | 2 | 1 |

I tried `=COUNTIF(D2:F1000,"*RC*")` and `=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",COUNTA(F2:Y,"*RBC*")))` and `=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A2:A="","",countifs(D2:D,"*RC*",E2:E,"*RC*",F2:F,"*RC*"` without any luck. I want to make it as array not to have to pull down the formula. There are about 20+ columns with access and about 4500 rows. Any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: you say Total BC, but counting RC instead...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Assume your data start from 'A1', put this formula in 'G2'.

```
=ArrayFormula(
 BYROW(D2:F,LAMBDA(ROW,
  IF(INDEX(ROW,1)="","",{SUM(INT(REGEXMATCH(ROW," RC$"))),SUM(INT(REGEXMATCH(ROW," SC$")))})
 ))
)
```

It uses `REGEXMATCH()` to match for `string` end with `" RC"` and `" SC"`, change the Boolean value to integer, and sum up the result.

As `TRUE` is equal to `1` in Excel and google sheet, this will return the number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

You were not on the wrong track with `COUNTIF`, you just had to add a `BYROW`.

Assuming your data is in A2:F, enter this formula in G2.

```
=ArrayFormula(BYROW(D2:F,LAMBDA(row,IF(COUNTA(row)=0,,COUNTIF(row,{"*RC*","*SC*"})))))
```